# Отсортировать значения c определенным количеством

Tags: java

У меня есть ряд чисел, например: `2, 6, 8, 13, 19, 26, 30, 39, 59` и одно число из этого ряда, например, 30.

Числа даны в случайном порядке.

Мне нужно сделать следующее:

1. Отсортировать по возрастанию набор чисел
2. Вывести первые четыре элемента отсортированного набора (При этом вывести не только само значение, но и его порядковый номер)
3. Проверить, входит ли заданное значение (напоминаю, выше в примере это число 30) в первые четыре отсортированных элемента. Если не входит -- вывести и его, указав дополнительно порядковый номер. Если входит -- ничего не выводить дополнительно.

Примеры.

Не входит (пример для числа 30):

```
1) 2
2) 6
3) 8
4) 13
7) 30
```

Входит (пример для числа 8):

```
1) 2
2) 6
3) 8
4) 13
```

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Что именно в этом задании вам непонятно? Что у вас уже реализовано?

Answer (score 5):

1. Закинь числа в `ArrayList`
2. Воспользуйся **[Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)**, чтобы отсортировать
3. Воспользуйся **[ArrayList.subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-)**, чтобы отрезать 4-ре элемента в другой список
4. Воспользуйся **[ArrayList.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)**, чтобы определить, есть ли дополнительный элемент в коллекции

   Если есть — финита ля комедия.

   Если нет — добавь.